# mongoose Model.create function returns undefined

Tags: node.js, rest, mongoose, mongoose-schema

The above query returns a 200 when I try to create a User, but whenever I log into MongoDB there is no collections created. Can anyone help ?

//user model

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type : String, 
        required  : true,
        trim : true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        lowercase: true,
        validate: value => {
            if(!validator.isEmail(value)){
                throw new Error({error : 'Invalid email address'})
            }
        }
    },
    password: {
        type: String, 
        required: true,
        minLength: 5
    },
    // a user can have multiple jobs
    jobs : [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Job'
    }],
    tokens: [{
        token: {
            type: String,
            required:  true
        }
    }]
})
const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
module.exports = User
```

// user functions written

```
  createUser(name, email, password){
        return User.create({name: name, email: email, password : password}, (err, docs) => {
            if(err){
                throw err.message;
            }

        });
    }
```

//routes.js

```
// user create
router.post('/users', async(req, res) => {
    try{
        const {name, email, password } = req.body
        const user = userManager.createUser(name, email, password); [1]
        res.status(200).json(user)
    }
    catch(error) {
        res.status(400).send({error : error.message})
    }
})
```

The line[1] returns undefined. Why ?
note : all module requirements are fulfilled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you create the `schema` you need to create a Model **FROM** that schema.

Example from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/mongoose):

```
// Define schema
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var SomeModelSchema = new Schema({
  a_string: String,
  a_date: Date
});

// Compile model from schema
var SomeModel = mongoose.model('SomeModel', SomeModelSchema );
```

Now after you create the model you can use `SomeModel.create`

**EDIT**:
`line[1]` will always return undefined because you are using `callbacks` and only way to get value out of callback is either push another callback(I would really discourage that). But best way is to use `Promises` now mongoose by default supports `Promises. So, basically for promises it will be,

```
// user functions written

async function createUser(name, email, password){
  try {
    return await User.create({ name: name, email: email, password: password });
  } catch (err) {
    throw err.message;
  }
}
```

In the router adda `await`:

```
const user = await userManager.createUser(name, email, password);
```

Comment: i cannot see that in the question. you created schema but not the model.

Comment: so why is this returning undefined ?

Comment: Edited the answer. Please read up async function in node.js a little.\

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you call an asynchronous function synchronously. It returned undefined because the function hasn't been resolved yet.
A solution could be to use [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) or [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await).

Example:

```js
async createUser(name, email, password) {
    const createdUser = await User.create({name,email,password});
    return creaatedUser;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something I ran into was you need to pass in an empty object if your not setting any fields - i.e.

Good: Model.create({})

Bad: Model.create()

Comment: that should be a note here, actually the main issue here was that mongoose.create is actually a asynchronous function and this returns a promise, so until and unless we wait for the promise to get resolved the value for mongoose.create will be undefined.

Comment: also why would I like to run mongoose.create if there is nothing that I would like to create. is it just to fill the default column values in the document ?